# How to read String response

Tags: android

Some API is reply with non-json string so how to read value data from response?

Response Format:

onSuccess Response:

> status=success:orderId=a089f02724ed4a8db6c069f6d30b3245:txnId=None:paymentId=MOJO7918005A76494611:token=qyFwLidQ0aBNNWlsmwHx1gHFhlt6A1

I need to read `orderID` and `txnid` it's not JSON.

I tried with splite by : but it's not proper working.

```
String message = "status=" + status + ":orderId=" + orderID + ":txnId=" 
                 + transactionID + ":paymentId=" + paymentID + ":token=" 
                 + Instamojo.this.accessToken;
```

String response created like this.

Comment: replace : with , and then convert it into json.

Comment: 1º Replace : with ,
2º Replace = with :
3º Prepend { and append } to the resulting string
4º Parse JSON
5º Profit (?)

Answer (score 4):

There is a cool way to convert the Instamojo string response to json response by using the following code snippet!

```
public void onInstaSuccess(String strResponse) {
    String strWithoutColon = strResponse.replace(":", "\",\"");
    String strWithoutEquals = strWithoutColon.replace("=", "\":\"");
    String perfectJSON = "{\"" + strWithoutEquals + "\"}";
    Log.i("Perfect", perfectJSON);
    // COnvert the json to POJO
    InstaMojoModel instaMojoModel = new Gson().fromJson(perfectJSON, InstaMojoModel.class);
}
```

Here is the Instamojo class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class InstaMojoModel {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("orderId")
@Expose
private String orderId;
@SerializedName("txnId")
@Expose
private String txnId;
@SerializedName("paymentId")
@Expose
private String paymentId;
@SerializedName("token")
@Expose
private String token;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
}

public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
}

public String getTxnId() {
    return txnId;
}

public void setTxnId(String txnId) {
    this.txnId = txnId;
}

public String getPaymentId() {
    return paymentId;
}

public void setPaymentId(String paymentId) {
    this.paymentId = paymentId;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to separate every parts of your response. Then look for the part that start with orderID using [String.startWith()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)). Finally get the value by obtaining the substring containing the value using [String.substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)). Use [String.lastIndexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) to obtain the index of the `=` symbol.

This should look like this:

```
String response = getResponse(); //Don't know how you obtain it but its for the example
String[] array = response.split(':');
String orderIdPart;
for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){ 
    if(array[i].startWith("orderId")){
        orderIdPart = array[i];
        break;
    }
}
int index = orderIdPart.lastIndexOf('=');
String value = orderIdPart.substring(index);
```

Edit:

If you want to avoid the loop you could use this (but it supposed its always followed by txnID) :

```
int begginingIndex = response.indexOf("orderId=") + "orderId=".length();
int endIndex = response.indexOf(":txnId");
String value = response.substring(begginingIndex, endIndex);
```

Comment: any alternative solution without for loop?

Comment: I edited to answer to this requirement. But this supposed that orderId part is always followed by txnID part